# Bitbake command fails with distro fsl-imx-xwayland

Tags: git, qt5, yocto, bitbake, imx6

I am trying to build a yocto toolchain with Qt5 for NXP Freescale i.MX6 board.
But I keep getting an error with any bitbake command line.
I also tried checking to HEAD branch for every layer, I get the same below error:

```
david@david-ubuntu:~/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/build$ bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5
NOTE: Your conf/bblayers.conf has been automatically updated.
NOTE: Your conf/bblayers.conf has been automatically updated.
WARNING: Host distribution "Ubuntu-18.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
Parsing recipes: 100% |#############################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:01:01
Parsing of 2321 .bb files complete (0 cached, 2321 parsed). 3049 targets, 267 skipped, 2 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-18.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "imx6qsabresd"
DISTRO            = "fsl-imx-xwayland"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "4.9.11-1.0.0"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp  neon        callconvention-hard        cortexa9"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
meta              
meta-poky         = "morty:78890ea22750804e3e9113e76f7ca3d7234c8342"
meta-oe           
meta-multimedia   = "morty:fe5c83312de11e80b85680ef237f8acb04b4b26e"
meta-freescale    = "morty:a398b50b7fc084a9e68cc3000c218d5028522a25"
meta-freescale-3rdparty = "morty:68314612e236cab1da82d72a0da62635a3523f84"
meta-freescale-distro = "morty:cd5c7a2539f40004f74126e9fdf08254fd9a6390"
meta-bsp          
meta-sdk          = "morty:daba3340ecd8b358e0c6c415baeee0fcae95c525"
meta-browser      = "morty:10f6e3778d823ee1be106c126216c6f941088fbf"
meta-gnome        
meta-networking   
meta-python       
meta-filesystems  = "morty:fe5c83312de11e80b85680ef237f8acb04b4b26e"
meta-qt5          = "morty:ff073f04109900fc07bf81e2f1df63c626caf342"

Initialising tasks: 100% |##########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:12
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: gnu-config-native-20150728+gitAUTOINC+b576fa87c1-r0 do_unpack: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"; export SSH_AGENT_PID="2272"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/sources/poky/scripts/native-intercept:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/sources/poky/scripts:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/sbin:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/sbin:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/bin:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/sources/poky/scripts:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/david/bin:/home/david/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"; export HOME="/home/david"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 branch --set-upstream master origin/master failed with exit code 128, output:
fatal: the '--set-upstream' option is no longer supported. Please use '--track' or '--set-upstream-to' instead.

ERROR: gnu-config-native-20150728+gitAUTOINC+b576fa87c1-r0 do_unpack: Function failed: base_do_unpack
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20150728+gitAUTOINC+b576fa87c1-r0/temp/log.do_unpack.3872
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gnu-config/gnu-config_git.bb:do_unpack) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 31 tasks of which 0 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  virtual:native:/home/david/yocto/fsl-release-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gnu-config/gnu-config_git.bb:do_unpack
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I found on another forum that something might be using obsolete arguments to git, but I am not able to downgrade git package and I also want to avoid reinstalling a previous version of Ubuntu.

Here is my poky config (local.conf)

```
MACHINE ??= 'imx6qsabresd'
DISTRO ?= 'fsl-imx-wayland'
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS = "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-native = " sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"
CONF_VERSION = "1"

DL_DIR ?= "${BSPDIR}/downloads/"
ACCEPT_FSL_EULA = "1"
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try backporting the fix (see [commit 20d0282c6](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/?id=20d0282c6048fe11b303e538dbf9109ccb0c467d) in poky) -- it seems to be exactly what the error message is telling you.

Be prepared to possibly fix other things as well if you want to run a Yocto release from 2016 in Ubuntu from 2018... but testing this specific issue should be quick.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, so would installing Ubuntu 16.04 fix all eventual issues ?

Comment: The only issue with hosts newer than Ubuntu 16.04 is that they were never tested (because they did not exist at  the time) so there may be incompatibilities that you need to deal with. I would not expect major issues and personally would rather run a newer host and fix some issues than use a host from 2016